# How to specify external library file locations when installing CPAN modules

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

I'm trying to get Perl's Finance::Quote module working after MacOS upgrade to 11.4. One of the dependencies is B::Keywords. B::Keywords installation fails a test with this error:

```
> sudo cpan B::Keywords
[...]
Can't open /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/keywords.h: No such file or directory at t/11keywords.t line 25
```

Digging around, I see that keywords.h exists on my system in this location:

`/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/keywords.h`

Is there a way to tell cpan (or cpanm, or some other installation tool) where to look for these headers? Or, any other approach to get this working would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like they removed the `keywords.h` from the `CORE` directory (relative to the path given from `$Config{archlibexp}`) for the system perl on macOS 10.14, see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/153558865647.1483.573481613491501077%40wrigleys.postgresql.org) bug report.

The reason you are not able to install `B::Keywords` is due to a failed test [11keywords.t](https://metacpan.org/release/RURBAN/B-Keywords-1.22/source/t/11keywords.t) see line 24. Some possible solutions:

- Install the module without running the tests (`sudo cpan -T B::Keywords`)
- [Submit an issue](https://github.com/rurban/b-keywords/issues) at the GitHub issue tracker so the author of the module can fix the problem.
- Install the module with [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) instead of using the system perl (I tested this and it worked fine here).

Comment: Note that Apple recommends that you not use the system perl it distributes: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/FileSystemProtections/FileSystemProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH2-SW1

Comment: Thanks Håkon and Brian --- I was reluctant to go the perlbrew route but if Apple is recommending against use of System perl that might be the best approach.

Comment: You've already left the eco system by not using the package manager used to install the `perl`. At that point, you might as well install your own.